# Bleed into margins automatically to prevent orphans?

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, margins, widows-orphans

When I set my papers, it sometimes happens that the last line of a paragraph is very short, in extreme cases just a single word, perhaps a page number.

I have set `\clubpenalty` to `10000`, of course, and tried to adjust spacing with `\looseness=-1`. Even so, I sometimes have to resort to `\rlap{}`, bleeding into the right margin, as it were. (See the line immedaitely below the image in the attached image).

Is there a way to do this automatically, i.e. for a very short line?

[image]

Comment: Bleeding is typographically much worse than orphaning. In your case, I would suggest you to reword the text so that it's a bit longer and the whole `Bedeutung~\cite[...]{...}` moves to the next line. Or to reword is so that it's a bit shorter. And btw, do you use `\usepackage{microtype}`? It might help as well.

Comment: This is just an example. I could certainly reword, or perhaps use another footnote, but I'm interested in a possible solution to the problem regardless.

Comment: You can set `\parfillskip` to `0pt plus ` some value below `\lineskip`. This will make sure the last line of the paragraph doesn't get too short. I don't think it will bleed into the margin; using `microtype` will make sure everything is rearranged approriately.

Comment: @Ingmar The issue is that _this problem has no general solution_. No matter what others claim (MS Word, Patoline, ...), it is impossible to some situations to get a reasonable automated results, and if you're not allowed to reword, some paragraphs will look bad, no matter what you do.

Comment: BTW, `\clubpenalty` refers to the first line of a paragraph. I think we mean `\widowpenalty` here. While there is disagreement on the meaning of "widows" and "orphans", Knuth uses "orphan" to refer to a page break after the first line of a paragraph and "widow" for a break before the last line.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using both, i.e. `\clubpenalty`and `\widowpenalty` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX is not capable of automated solution for your problem. You can always need to observe the log for bad boxes. You have several options for solutions:

- re-word the text (preferred solution)
- try to use `{\sloppy Your problematic paragraph.\par}` or the `sloppypar` einvironment (reasonable solution)
- allow a widow or an orphan (reasonable solution)
- force an overfull line (bad solution)

What you do is in the end up to you, but you've been warned.